# How can I create scheduled queries in Google BigQuery using an Amazon S3 dataset located in an AWS region?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-bigquery

I've been creating scheduled queries in Google BigQuery for a while now, mostly in the multi-region US location. When I try to create a query on a dataset pulled from an Amazon S3 bucket, though, I get one of the following errors:

- Error creating scheduled query: Destination dataset is not supported in REGION_AWS_US_EAST_1
- Error creating scheduled query: Internal error

I can manually run the query, but only if the data is going to a temporary table. If I try to manually run the query to create a new table in the AWS dataset, it runs endlessly with no error message and nothing happening.

Is there a way to run scheduled queries in an AWS region for BigQuery? If not, is there a way to automatically transfer data from an Amazon S3 bucket to a non-AWS region?

Answer (score 0):

Scheduled Query does not support destination datasets in Omni regions. Instead, you could take one of the following approaches:

1. Write query results to S3 instead of a BigQuery dataset: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/omni-aws-export-results-to-s3
2. Use the S3 data transfer to transfer data to a non-Omni region: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/s3-transfer